# Como conectar o Windows Phone a um SQL Server?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, windows-phone

Gostaria de saber como faço pra acessar e receber dados de um servidor a partir do Windows Phone. Simplificando: tenho um PC e quero acessar um documento diretamente do smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

O Windows Phone não foi feito exatamente pra conectar a uma instância do SQL Server porque a própria Microsoft não permite. O correto seria ele conectar a um website que tenha uma Web API implementada nele.

Em todo caso, tem uma versão do Google Drive para Windows Phone para acesso a documentos:

http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/google-drive-on-wp/b3e46abe-5fc6-48c5-b4ab-c27acc4d5308

Answer (score 2):

Aplicações móveis não podem se comunicar diretamente com bancos de dados relacionais.
Para qualquer integração de dados/persistência em uma fonte externa. É necessário um backend na web que permita uma interação via API.

Existem alguns serviços de armazenamento na nuvem que disponibilizam níveis gratuitos de utilização, como por exemplo o [Parse](http://www.parse.com) e o [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com).

Answer (score 2):

Se o requisito é mesmo ligar ao SQL Server sem mais nada, é sempre possível [criar um endpoint SOAP](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms181591.aspx).

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia
o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter 
conteúdo aqui mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta;  
você poderia fazer isso?
Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! 
Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: 
[Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, é um link para a documentação oficial do SQL Server. Se o link deixar de funcionar, é porque a funcionalidade deixou de existir há muito tempo.

Comment: Mas se alguém utilizar uma versão desatualizada, pode precisar disso documentado...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, agora não entendi.

Comment: Tipo, se alguém, algum dia usar uma versão descontinuada (e que não tenha mais esse link), mas continue precisando da informação...

Comment: Peço desculpa, @FilipeAvelar, mas continuo a não entender a tua reclamação. Este não é o forum para reportar falhas de documentação do SQL Server.

Comment: Concordo. Respostas com pouco mais do que um link *podem* ser boas respostas: e esta e' uma delas. O Paulo aconcelhou usar um endpoint SOAP. Explicar *como* usa-lo nao cabe numa resposta so'. Agora cabe ao OP pesquisar mais informacao - e havera' melhor sitio do que a documentacao oficial?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, o aplicativo do Windows Phone pode fazer uma chamada HTTP para um Web API. No servidor, pode fazer um project `Web API`. O Microsoft tem muitos recursos sobre Web API, como funciona, e como fazer um. Uma fonte exelente é o próprio site deles (em inglês), http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 1):

Uma observacao em relacao aos outros comentarios:

O Windows Phone nao permite ligar a uma base de dados ***remota***!

No entanto, e' perfeitamente possivel ligar a uma base de dados local (ex: SQLite). Na verdade, este e' o metodo predominante tanto no Windows Phone, como noutras plataformas moveis (Android, iOS, WinRT).

Como usar SQLite no Windows Phone: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone